# Does Dask allow indexing with a Dask series?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm seeing behavior that looks like a bug in Dask, but I want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

I have a Dask data frame called `labeled_texts`. It contains a column called "text". I calculate a Dask series called `label_rows` which contains boolean values and is of the same length as `labeled_texts`. I use it to index into `labeled_texts` and from that smaller dataframe I get the "text" column like so.

```
labeled_text[label_rows]["text"].compute()
```

I get `KeyError: 'text'` way down in Dask/Pandas code when I run the above line. However, the following commands work

```
labeled_text[label_rows].compute()["text"]
labeled_text[label_rows.compute()]["text"]
```

I think all three commands should produce the same result and the first should not cause an error. Is this correct?

Unfortunately, I am unable to come up with a minimal repro scenario that I can post here. The problem happens consistently on one particular cluster, but the same code and data running on a different machine works fine. (Which further makes me think this is a Dask bug.)

Without a better repro scenario I don't expect anyone to be able to solve this problem for me. I just want to make sure that I'm not doing something wrong.

---

Here is the full stack trace.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  ...my code that ultimately calls compute()...

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 175, in compute
      (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 446, in compute
      results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2510, in get
      results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1812, in gather
      asynchronous=asynchronous,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 753, in sync
      self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 337, in sync
      six.reraise(*error[0])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
      raise value
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 322, in f
      result[0] = yield future
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
      value = future.result()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1668, in _gather
      six.reraise(type(exception), exception, traceback)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
      raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/optimization.py", line 1059, in __call__
      return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 149, in get
      result = _execute_task(task, cache)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
      return func(*args2)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
      indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
      return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  KeyError: 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing sticks out to me.  As you suggest, I recommend trying to provide a minimal reproducver.